# Variation on Markov / Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X$ is a random variable taking on both positive and negative real values such that $E(X) = \mu$ and $var(X) = \sigma^2 < \infty$.

I'm trying to find the tightest inequality such that

$$P(X - \mu\geq \epsilon) \leq F(\mu, \sigma, \epsilon)$$

I know from Chebyshev that $P(|X - \mu| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$, and if $X$ were nonnegative then Markov's inequality is $P(X \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\mu}{\epsilon}$.

But neither seem to help with this one-tail estimate.

Comment: Would you be more specific about what kind of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

So, in general, if $X$ is a nonnegative random variable, and $f$ is a monotone increasing positive function, $f: \mathbb R_+ \rightarrow \mathbb R_+$, and $\mathbb E f(X) < \infty$, then $\mathbb P(X > x) \le \frac {\mathbb E f(X)} {f(x)}$.

Proof: 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb E f(X) &= \mathbb E[f(X) \cdot 1\{X \ge x\}] + \mathbb E[f(X) \cdot 1\{X < x\}] \\\
&\ge \mathbb E[f(X) \cdot 1\{X \ge x\}] \\\
&\ge f(x) \cdot \mathbb E[1\{X \ge x\}] \\\
&= f(x) \cdot \mathbb P(X \ge x)
\end{align}$$

where $1$ is the indicator function.

Markov's inequality and Chebychev's inequality are special cases of this lemma, where Markov's follows from $f(x) = x$ for example. So potentially in your situation you could get a tighter bound on $|X|$ by a careful choice of $f$.

Other potential bounds include: [Chernoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) bounds and [Kolmogorov's maximal inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_inequality)